# Increase listings spacing through the package listings or use figure instead?

Tags: spacing, floats, listings

This is more a conceptional question on how to use LaTeX in the right way. So far I have striven to customize only those things in LaTeX which are supposed to be without messing to much with print space.

I would like to increase the top and bottom spacing of `listings` to the rest of the text. I inserted a `listing` and it was put directly on to the next line, which is to close to the text.

Should I increase this space by using listings option or should I just put it into a `figure`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 4.3 of [the listings manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) shows `aboveskip` and `belowskip` options. Have you tried those yet?